# Facebook retrieves wrong (old) image from the page to create its preview (wall story)

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I use facebook share button for every post in my blog.
(http://loveclubhouse.blogspot.com/)

When there was no Open Graph meta tag included in my blog, facebook would retrieve the first picture from the post's page to make a preview story on the sharer's wall for this post.

Once, I added an Open Graph image meta tag to my blog:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
```

However, the size of *postImageThumbnails* turned out to be too small, so I decided not to use them anymore and removed the above metnioned Open Graph meta tag from my blog.

The problem is:

Even though I removed all Open Graph meta tags from my blog, facebook still somehow creates preview stories for my posts based on those tiny *data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl* and doesn't want anymore to retrieve the first pictures from posts content as it was before I made any changes in my blog.

Answer (score 2):

Try facebook [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool, it deletes the cache as well.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer... With [a little more rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) you'll be able to comment anywhere...

Comment: But it actually solves the problem. If you debug your url, it deletes the cache as well.